# Google Chart color of gridline margin

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

[image: gridlinecolor]

What option from Google Chart Api change the color of that lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use option --> `baselineColor`

on either / both --> `hAxis`, `vAxis`

```
var options = {
  hAxis: {
    baselineColor: 'magenta',
  },
  vAxis: {
    baselineColor: 'magenta',
  }
};
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'y'],
    [0, 1],
    [1, 2],
    [2, 3],
  ]);

  var options = {
    hAxis: {
      baselineColor: 'magenta',
    },
    vAxis: {
      baselineColor: 'magenta',
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(
    document.getElementById('chart_div')
  );
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Sure, thank you. P.S.: I know how it work, but didn't found the name of object for color (`baseline`).